# Nuget vs referencing another project in another team project in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, nuget

In general, when is it better to:

1. set up cloaking or branching, vs.
2. use nuget or another package manager (with the package restore feature)

to reference a class library or other project that lives in a different Team Project in TFS?

Answer (score 1):

I think ultimately this is a personal choice, but I can tell you what my choice would be.

I prefer the **NuGet** route.  I have a private **NuGet** repository (or you can use **MyGet**) and publish any common libraries I may want to use between projects to that.  I can then pull these down in different projects that require the library.

`Some advantages to this technique over referencing the project directly are:`

1. Fine control over the versioning of the library
2. Ability to introduce major/breaking changes to the library without breaking every project that depends on it (again achieved through versioning)
3. Easily share the libraries with other projects that are not in the same source control system.
4. Quickly make the library public if that is a goal.

`Some disadvantages`

1. Setup of **NuGet** repository and packaging files takes an extra step.
2. The debugging story is a little more complex, but in theory your library should have a suite of **Unit Tests** so debugging shouldn't be necessary in the consuming application.

Hopefully others can add to this list of pros and cons.